# vscode debugging fails with multiple Azure Functions in workspace project

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, azure-functions, multiple-projects

I have two Azure function apps in a vscode workspace running properly locally on their own ports (this was made by changing the `host start` to `host start --port 7072` in one of the app's tasks.json file.

So far, when running any of the apps in vscode it works just as it should with debugging and all.

In the code-workspace file I've added the following configuration:

```json
"launch": {
  "compounds": [
    {
      "name": "All Azure function apps",
      "configurations": ["App1", "App2"],
    }
  ]
}
```

This starts both applications and they work as they should, but the debugger does not seem to attach properly and I get a warning message saying that "No process with the specified id is currently running.".

[image: No process with the specified id is currently running.]

It seems that there's just something small missing to make vscode understand how to attach the debugger, but I can't figure out exactly what and how to do this.